# Where is Prevention Policy blade in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-security

I'm working on an official Azure online Tutorial that asks me to follow following steps in Azure Portal. But as the image below shows there is no `Prevention Policy` link on the blade. **Question**: What I may be missing here? **Note**: I'm using free trial subscription.

```
To configure your recommendations navigate to the Security Center blade. Then, perform the following steps:

 1. Click Security policy in the left pane.
 2. In the middle pane, click the subscription that you want to configure. Note that each subscription has its own independent Security Center settings.
 3. In the Security policy blade, ensure that data collection is turned on. Then, click 'Prevention policy'.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To set up a security policy for all Azure resources:**

- On the Security Center dashboard, select **Security policy**, and then select **your subscription**.
- Select **Security policy**.
- Turn on or turn off policy items that you want to apply to all Azure resources.
- When you're finished selecting your settings, select OK.
- On the **Security policy** blade, select **Save**.

[image]

**To set up a policy for a specific resource group:**

- On the Security Center dashboard, select **Security policy**, and then
  select a **resource group**.
- Under **INHERITANCE**, select **Unique**.
- Select the pricing **Free** or **Standard**.
- select **Save**.
  [image]

Comment: So in your first image, what you are showing on the extreme right is the prevention policy. I can see that blade on my portal as well but its title does not say `Prevention Policy`.

Comment: @nam Due do some changes in the portal, previously we have policy components where you can see the "Prevention Policy" tab. But now Prevention Policy is included in Security Policy tab as shown in the Image1. Note: They have removed the naming as prevention policy.

Comment: Got it (thank you). The tutorial I'm working on has pre-warned the users that since Azure changes are ongoing Microsoft will try to update the course material accordingly but some areas may still be a bit outdated; however they would try to update them ASAP.

Comment: @nam Glad to know your issue has been addressed.